# Npm install locking pipeline Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline in Jenkins to build an Angular 6 project, in the Jenkinsfile that runs the command `sh "npm install --production"`to install the dependencies and then execute `nb build...`, however, **npm install** is with some problem that I can not identify because the pipeline hangs on it and the time can vary from 5 minutes up to 60 minutes or even longer and this is damaging the automatic build.

I've already tried replacing `npm install`,`npm ci` and now I'm doing this:

```
stage('Install') {
    steps {
        sh "rm -rf node_modules/* && npm cache clean --force"
        sh "npm install --production"
    }
}
```

I just added `rm -rf node_modules/* && npm cache clean --force` to see if it resolves, but it did not work.

My Jenkinsfile is this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        docker { 
            image "node:8.12.0"
        } 
    }

    stages {
        stage('Install') {
            steps {
                sh "rm -rf node_modules/* && npm cache clean --force"
                sh "npm install --production"
            }
        }

        stage('Build Project') {
            steps {
                sh  '$(npm bin)/ng build --prod --output-path=docker/dist'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A few things - is that the generic node image?  If so I don't think it contains the angular cli and if it does it would be available as a command just like npm - no need to do $(npm bin). Next getting rid of the node_modules folder doesn't need the '/*' suffix just delete the whole thing.  Next I don't see a reason to remove the global npm cache - that's sort of outdated as I understand it.  Finally, do you see evidence that the rm -rf ran?  If not maybe an issue with the docker environment starting up the node image.

Comment: The image is just an official Node image. My main problem is that the process gets stuck in `npm install --production` and I would like to know a way to solve it or where I can find the problem (since it does not error during execution, it just gets stopped in this command)?

Comment: You might want to check the networking configuration for the docker installation.  you could run 'docker run -i node:8.12.0 /bin/bash' and check that you have network connectivity, although the image probably doesn't have any of the network diags tools in it.  You could for example run the npm command to install angular npm install -g @angular/cli' to see if that will run.  This will at least determine if you have a jenkins problem or a docker problem.

Comment: I ran the `ping 8.8.8.8` command and it worked fine and then I ran `npm install -g @ angular/cli` and returned it: `/usr/local/bin/ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@7.1.3
added 292 packages from 178 contributors in 37.931s`. And he stood still.

Comment: I did another test, in the Node container I accessed the /home/node directory, created a package.json file the same as the one I'm using in the project and executed `npm install --production` and the command was executed normally. Now I do not know what might be happening with the container created by the pipeline.

Comment: I added the `--loglevel verbose` parameter to `npm install` to see the log, during the GET of the packages it simply stops at a certain point in any package. What can cause this pause in the package? I have already tested with versions 8.12.0, 8.14.0, 8.14.0-alpine ... but I do not know if it really is the version. Could it be space occupied by packages?

Comment: I'd say you rules out the version of the image you're using. After poking around a bit, the only think I've found is this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43594 which suggests that you might be running up against a memory limit...

Comment: I think it's not memory, it follows data from memory and CPU that I got through `docker stats`.... **CPU%: 0.00** and **MEN USAGE / LIMIT:109MiB / 8.614GiB**